# iMacros / Firefox / format result

Tags: javascript, firefox, csv, imacros

I'm trying to extract some part of a website with this (simplified) code in javascript.

```
macro2 = "CODE:";
macro2 += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro2 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=U:\imacros FILE=test.csv" + "\n";
```

So, I get the right values and the are saved in the csv. So far no problem.
But the markup of the website is:

```
<h2>
    content
</h2>
```

So, each value in my csv is added with an extra hard return.
Is there any way to avoid this? With some HTML tag stripping or something?

Any input will be much appreciated!
Thank you.
/jurgen

Answer (score 0):

put this between the line 2 and 3:

```
macro2 += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var text=\\"{{!EXTRACT}}\\";var text = text.replace(\'\\\\n\',\'\',\'g\');text;")' + "\n";
```

or shorter:

```
macro2 += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var text=\\"{{!EXTRACT}}\\";var text = text.trim();text;")' + "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!
I tried doing that but I get: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal, line: 5 (Error code: -1001)

Comment: @JurgenLandrie sorry I forgot to properly escape the new line - once for imacros and twice for javascript so the result is the funny looking \\\\n. or instead of 'replace' you could use the shorter text.trim() :)

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.. trim didn't do the job. But replace worked just fine, even for the hard returns.
Now to figure out how to add a header above all extractions I save in my .csv :)