# imacros javascript save data to file giving error in firefox

Tags: javascript, imacros

When I execute this javascript .js file in firefox it gives error

```
SyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line: 1 (Error code: -910)
```

This url on alexa there has 25 results per each page and there are 20 pages like this. I need to capture all 25 x 20 = 500 results and save them to file.

```
var jsLF="\n";

var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/ID" + jsLF; 
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF; 

var macro1;
macro1  =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries;{{j}}/ID" + jsLF; 

//loop all the pages for each page get data
for (var j=0;j<3;j++)
{
iimDisplay(j);    
iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay(macro1);
//iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{j}}jsLF SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\ FILE=hiprsites.txt");

//loop the first page and get result
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(macro);
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{i}}jsLF SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\   FILE=hiprsites.txt");
}
```

Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit for the new requirements you provided. I think you want something like the code bellow. Take a close look at the changes to be able to replicate them in your future macros. Also mind that ID is the country code for Indonesia, so with the bellow macro you'll get the 500 results for that country. Change that code with the one you need for your country.

```
var jsLF="\n";

var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\   FILE=hiprsites.txt" + jsLF;

var macro1;
macro1  =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries;{{j}}/ID" + jsLF; 

//loop all the pages for each page get data
for (var j=0;j<20;j++)
{
iimDisplay(j);    
iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay(macro1);

//loop the current page and get all 25 result
for(var i=1;i<=25;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(macro);
iimSet("i",i);
}
}
```

PS: It is not tested, but it should work. If it doesn't let me know.

Comment: Modified the script as symbiotech and Bestmacros suggested. updated the new script. little better this time but I am getting only result values as "0,1,2" saving now. it is suppose to save the website urls as needed. can you suggest where is the mistake

Comment: wow! this worked. few things.  it is saving 3 lines for each entry.

Comment: for each entry it is saving "", url, "" it is saving quotes and actual data and then quotes. do you know how to avoid this saving

Comment: REPLACED the line "macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;" with  "macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;"  now it is not saving that extra lines.  but still it is saving each entry with suffix and prefix double quotes. we need to remove it can you help

Comment: @user2994113 You cannot avoid the "", they are part of Imacros format to compose a valid csv file. You can however change the extension of your file from .txt to .csv . This way when you open the file in excel those double quotes will be gone and you can export it a something else.

Comment: MY Bad, changing the TAG Value saving other unnecessary values. pretty much i have to go with your original script, But please suggest how to get rid of extra lines it is adding. for each entry it is adding quotes in 1st line and 3rd line. so for 25 results i am getting 75 records inserted with 50 records quotes can you suggest how to get rid of it. there is a javascript function replace to remove strings but not sure how to use it here.

Comment: SO have 2 issues, issue # 1- remove extract lines that it it inserting. (2) issue # 2-  remove double quotes that it is inserting before and after extracted value

Comment: @user2994113 about the double quotes please read again my above comment. for the newlines try this answer and its comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892124/imacros-firefox-format-result/16896788#16896788

Comment: this is really needed to remove quotes. as this is the input for my next script. without this i am stuck can you help me please

Comment: i modified the script as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892124/imacros-firefox-format-result/16896788#16896788. now it is writing 1 line, but still lines are written with quotes prefix and suffix. do you know how to remove quotes before after i tried to use this but it is giving syntax error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047225/imacros-writing-double-quotes-to-html-file-why

Comment: we are so close please help me with this last issue

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
iimSet("i", i);    
iimPlay(macro);
iimSet("i", i);   
iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{i}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\ FILE=hiprsites.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. i tried it but no luck. still getting same error.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. i tried it but no luck. still getting same error. this statement is giving error SyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line: 1 (Error code: -910)   iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT{{i}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\ FILE=hiprsites.txt");